# SQL view selecting from multiple tables single source

Tags: sql, join, view

So I have been looking all over SO for an answer to this question but I cant seem to find one, so if there is one I'm sorry for the duplicate post.

The problem I have is this

I have a table that refrences multiple items in differnt tables. It is setup like this

This is the main reference table ( the one that holds all the items to be referenced )

```
ID:key
itemID:item refrenced
```

I then have the other tables for things like

```
Speakers
Sessions
Sponsors
```

These tables are what the refrence table will point to. What I want to get back is a simple subset, meaning the refrence table 'itemID' field will map to the  itemID field of the other tables.

What I would like to have happen is that any item that is found will display in the results, meaning it will look in all 3 tables for the itemID that matches and display out the data.

So for example

In the reference table you may have

```
ID:1 , itemID: 1111
ID:2 , itemID: 2222
ID:3 , itemID: 3333
ID:4 , itemID: 4444
ID:5 , itemID: 5555
```

So we have 5 items in our reference table, I want to look in all three tables for a match on itemID

```
Speakers
Sessions
Sponsors
```

If there is a match it should return from the table

```
itemsID, Title
```

When I try an do this from the view in SQL it returns no results, I'm guessing the join is incorrect and I admit I am not very good with joins..

Anyhow I hope this somewhat makes sense and any information you could provide me with would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can create a view with a union clause (assuming that itemId is unique across all tables)

```
SELECT ref_table.ID, ref_table.ItemId, speakers.title 
FROM ref_table, speakers
WHERE ref_table.itemId = speakers.ItemId
UNION
SELECT ref_table.ID, ref_table.ItemId, sessions.title 
FROM ref_table, sessions
WHERE ref_table.itemId = sessions.ItemId
...
```

Now to query the table using the id, you do

```
SELECT * FROM my_view WHERE id = ?
```

Answer (score 0):

Use UNION and then join with reference table

```
Select R.itemId, T.title 
From
(
     Select itemid, title ,'speakers' as type
    from speakers
    UNION
    Select itemid, title ,'sessions' as type
    from sessions 
) T
Join refTable R
On R.itemid = T.itemId
```